# Why does xgalley require a blank line before \end{document}?

Tags: errors, xgalley

The following MWE gives this error:

```
! Improper \prevdepth.
\newpage ...everypar {}\fi \par \ifdim \prevdepth 
                                                  >\z@ \vskip -\ifdim \prevd...
l.5 \end{document}
```

If I insert a blank line before `\end{document}` it compiles without error. Why is this? Is it expected behaviour?

**MWE:**

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xgalley}
\begin{document}
Why is a blank line required below this?
\end{document}
```

**Relevant file versions:**

```
   xgalley.sty    2017/11/14 L3 Experimental galley
    xparse.sty    2017/11/14 L3 Experimental document command parser
     expl3.sty    2017/11/14 L3 programming layer (loader) 
expl3-code.tex    2017/11/14 L3 programming layer 
 l3pdfmode.def    2017/03/18 v L3 Experimental driver: PDF mode
 xtemplate.sty    2017/11/14 L3 Experimental prototype document functions
  l3galley.sty    2017/11/14 L3 Experimental galley code
```

Comment: Your version is compilable without errors with an earlier (2016) version.

Comment: Curiously enough, the difference between the current `xgalley.sty` and the one in TL 2016 is only in the release date.

Comment: Presumably this is due to a 2e kernel change ... I'll take a look

Comment: @JohnKormylo Note that we do a lot of work with `\everypar` in `xgalley`: there is a 'user' level version but that is not the primitive

Comment: @JosephWright -  I see that your problem with \everypar is not the same as mine.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The issue arises due to the addition of some code to the LaTe2e `\newpage` macro ('[newpage prevdepth fix](https://github.com/latex3/latex2e/commit/e942adc86237dec5073b51fa748f8bdacec05323)'). This adds a test for `\prevdepth` to `\newpage`: this happens just after a `\par` token. When `xgalley` is loaded, the meaning of the `\par` token is modified to expand following material before inserting the primitive. That is almost always OK, but here we stumble as we can't expand the `\ifdim\prevdepth` test without inserting a `par` primitive. The solution to stop the expansion by adding a `\relax`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xgalley}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\patchcmd{\newpage}{\par}{\par\relax}{}{\FAILED}
\begin{document}
Why is a blank line required below this?
\end{document}
```

Comment: I'll raise this with the team: it could be fixed at either end ...